# In Tableau, is it possible to show percentages only in total columns?

Tags: formatting, percentage, tableau-api

In Tableau, is it possible to create a percentage of a measure and only have the percentage label show up in the total or grand total column?

For example, consider this simple table:

`|         | September | October | Totals |
+---------+-----------+---------+--------+
| Apples  |       157 |      99 |    256 |
+---------+-----------+---------+--------+
| Oranges |        12 |      37 |     49 |
+---------+-----------+---------+--------+`

What I'd love to get instead would be:

`|         | September | October | Totals        |
+---------+-----------+---------+---------------+
| Apples  |       157 |      99 |    256 83.93% |
+---------+-----------+---------+---------------+
| Oranges |        12 |      37 |     49 16.07% |
+---------+-----------+---------+---------------+`

The few problems I've seen so far are:

1. If I let Tableau calculate percentage for the table, it applies the percentage on the measure to every cell in the table.
2. If I add another measure with percentage in the marks card and add that as a text label, it also appears in every cell, but underneath the previous label instead of to the side.

Comment: Tough one. I don't believe you can (meaning I don't know how to do it) display a measure just for the total (and not for every cell). But if you can accept that, and the problem is (on 2) being underneath it, you can click on Text (on Marks card) then on the "..." box. There you can format how the text will appear

Comment: What does your raw data look like? I have found so many ways to hack things like this using special Calc fields like If month(date) = 9 or month (date) =10 then Null else Num/Den end. Very much depends on your data structure. If you post some of your raw data I can see to accomplish what you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I spoke with Tableau, and they recommended that a dashboard is created with two different worksheets. One worksheet would have the table with the numeric totals only, and the other worksheet would just be the grand total column. It's effective and seems to work well.